# The Search For More Worldbuilding or Speculative Evolution

Tags: discussion

Does anyone here know a list of other speculative evolution and/or worldbuilding websites or forums that I can go to and post discussion questions other than here, the Wiki, the ZetaBoard or the Reddit?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you meant when you included Reddit but just to be clear, /r/worldbuilding/ is completely independent from Worldbuilding SE.

So, that's one place to look for if you haven't done it yet.

- http://www.thecbg.org/ : A community of campaign builder, like the Forgotten Realms for example. Your questions could somewhat fit into their topics.